# Joomla 2.5 - Custom hand coded form and PHP mailer - Can't find the contact.php file

Tags: php, html, joomla, submit, contact-form

I'm working on a new Joomla 2.5 site running under *XAMPP*. I have written a custom estimating form in HTML as an Article.... A jQuery file for calc's and a contact.php file to email all calc's and client info.

As for using a form plug-in I don't think this is possible because of all of the calculations ... sliders ect. going on.

The problem is when I hit the submit button, joomla can't seem to find the contact.php file.
I am running XAMPP and have located the contact.php file in the root of my project.

***Here's the link to my Article with the form***

```
http://localhost/cleardraft/index.php/hosting/2012-02-17-02-08-39/estimate
```

***Link which is being returned that can't be found when clicking the Submit button. I was not expecting a link like this to the contact.php file***

```
http://localhost/cleardraft/index.php/hosting/2012-02-17-02-08-39/contact.php
```

**Sample of HTML**

```
<form id="wizard-form" method="post" action="contact.php" class="jWizard">

 <!------normal form code stuff here----->

<button type="submit" class="button-finish" style="display: inline-block; ">Submit</button>
```

I have searched and searched but have found no answers online.

Comment: Depending on your settings, Joomla may be doing a URL rewrite... what happens if you set your action to the file directly like: action="http://localhost/cleardraft/contact.php" 
assuming thats the file location... make sure to include the http:// before it... stack overflow is not showing that and i'm on my mobile

Comment: Thanks for your response Jeffery. I just tried doing a direct route as you suggested. I also tried ../cleardraft/contact.php but no luck. As for the 404 not found message its still showing the path as http://localhost/cleardraft/index.php/hosting/2012-02-17-02-08-39/contact.php

Comment: Lets say for instance that you created a test.php file in your root with a simple html contents of 'test'.... when you access localhost/cleardraft/test.php from your browser, do u get any ouput?

Comment: I navigated to the root of cleardraft with firefox and clicked on phpTest.php it opened and displayed the HTML content as it should.

Comment: my guess is that you have an .htaccess file that is causing the issues... what happens if you throw a simple form submit into your phpTest.php file and post it to a phpTestSubmit.php file? Does it route correctly?

Comment: K did the test as stated above...this is the error Chrome reported...XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/cleardraft/contact.php. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143093/origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin

Comment: I run xampp on localhost as well... you may have to set some config in your vhosts file for that direcotry... what version of xampp r u running?

Comment: Thanks Jeffery .... even if disabling Access-Control-Allow-Origin worked it still wont solve the problem. I'm still looking for clues on google...

Comment: I never set this particular sight as a Vhost in xampp .. That could be it though...I think I will just upload what I have to the shared server and see if it behaves the same. By the way...Very nice website you have...Are you the owner?

Comment: Hey richard, try to setup a vhosts entry and see what happens, btw, I am one of two owners

Comment: try using `<?php echo JURI::root() . 'cleardraft/contact.php' ?>` for the post

Comment: I have solved the Problem.... will post answer to the problem tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

(Solved by the OP in a question edit. Moved to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> **Solved...** * *Solved...* *  **Solved...**

```
<form id="wizard-form" method="post" action="http://localhost/cleardraft/contact.php" class="jWizard"> <--Direct Path Here.
```

> This is was hanging out at the bottom of my HTML file! Totally forgot about!!!!!! this was the cause of my headache!!!

```
$('form#wizard-form').bind('submit', function() {
    $('.R_C_loader').show();
    $.post("http://localhost/cleardraft/contact.php", <--Direct Path here and Solved it.
           $("#wizard-form").serialize(), 

           function(reply) {
               $(".R_C_message, #R_C_TopMessage").removeClass().html(reply);
               $('.R_C_loader').hide();
           });

    return false;

});
```